# Jacoco - What does ''class missed'' mean?

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I didn't find enough information for MISSEDCOUNT

```
<rules>
  <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
    <element>BUNDLE</element>
    <limits>
      <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
        <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
        <minimum>0.80</minimum>
      </limit>
      <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
        <counter>CLASS</counter>
        <value>MISSEDCOUNT</value>
        <maximum>0</maximum>
      </limit>
    </limits>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

I also encountered an error:

`Rule violated for bundle xxxx: classes missed count is 1, but expected maximum is 0)`

Could you give me a simple example when it could be thrown as well as should i use this check(MISSEDCOUNT) in my java project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MISSEDCOUNT` refers to the number of branches/classes/etc. (in this case classes because you have used `CLASS`) which are not tested. Using `MISSEDCOUNT` with a value of `0` will cause the build to fail if there are *any* classes that are not tested.

The error makes sense, because it sounds like there is 1 class in your project which is not tested (`classes missed count is 1`), but because you have specified a maximum of 0 allowable classes to be missed (`expected maximum is 0`), the build has failed.

See: http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html#rules

Whether or not you "should" use the `MISSEDCOUNT` check is entirely up to you. If you want to enforce comprehensive testing, then yes, I would include it. If there are some classes which simply cannot be tested for some reason, then you can always increase the count.